# Test jquery ajax call using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have following javascript code in my script file and I am writing test for the following function using JEST

```
function getData() {
    var $messageBar = $("#message-bar");
    var messageBarLength = $messageBar.length;
    if (messageBarLength == 0) return;
    var apiUrl = $messageBar.attr("data-url");
    if (messageBarLength && apiUrl) {
        apiUrl = apiUrl.replace("{c}/{l}/{s}/{cs}"
        
        $.get(apiUrl)
            .done(function (html) {
                if (html) {
                    $messageBar.html(html);
                } else {
                    $messageBar.hide();
                }
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                $messageBar.hide();
            });
    }
}
```

And my jest test is as below

```
test("test",
    () => {

        const jqXHR = {
            done: jest.fn().mockImplementation(cb => {
                
                return this;
            }),
            fail: jest.fn().mockImplementation(cb => {
               
                return this;
            })
        };
        
        $.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => jqXHR);
        $.get();
        getData();
        expect($.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Test is running fine but in code coverage, its showing `done` and 'fail` is not covered. I already spent one day but did not find any solution
Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: your `jqXHR` methods don't invoke the given callbacks (`cb`)

Comment: I already tried not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `XHR.done` callback has branches (when it's called with `html` and without `html`) you will have to mock it as a function that calls the callback

- once with a value

  ```
        const xhr = {
          done: jest.fn((cb) => {
            cb();
            return xhr;
          }),
          fail: jest.fn((cb) => {
            cb();
            return xhr;
          }),
        };
  ```
- once without a value

  ```
        const xhr = {
          done: jest.fn((cb) => {
            cb('<span>some HTML</span>');
            return xhr;
          }),
          fail: jest.fn((cb) => {
            cb();
            return xhr;
          }),
        };
  ```

[here is a working example](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/PuzzledClosedBruteforceprogramming#getSiteWideMessageBar.test.js) with 100% coverage

Comment: Thanks a lot for code snippet.I am getting this exception ` TypeError: $messageBar.html is not a function`

Comment: @santoshsingh take a look at how have I mocked `jquery` at the top of the test file